# Showing allowed HTTP methods

Tags: python, http, rest, methods

I want to get the allowed HTTP methods with the HTTP OPTIONS method, like this:

```
telnet site.com 80
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 14 Oct 2012 21:04:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

How can I do this using Python libs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('w3.com')
conn.request('OPTIONS', '/')
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.getheader('allow')
```

The result is

```
OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
```