# Python equivalent for curl TRACE

Tags: python, python-requests, trace

Is there a python equivalent for checking if a host accepts the trace method?

`curl -sIX TRACE neopets.com`

Note, I'm not trying to get a request traceback, I'm also not trying to get my raw request. I'm trying to verify if a webserver supports the TRACE method.

https://curl.trillworks.com/ translates the command to:

`requests.head('http://neopets.com')` but it doesn't seem to get me the same result as the curl.

EDIT: I guess I have to construct the request

```
req = requests.Request('TRACE', 'https://google.com')
r = req.prepare()
s = requests.Session()
s.send(r)
```

Comment: [Maybe this stackoverflow question helps you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application)

Comment: @KevinHernandez no I'm not trying to get a traceback

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. SOrry about that let me delete my answer

Comment: No problem, don't know who downvoted but would be nice to get some feedback as to why it got downvoted.

Comment: [I know it is a late reply but try this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886589/showing-allowed-http-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to check if the TRACE method is accepted, you can use the OPTIONS method instead. The available methods will be returned in the `Allow` header.

```
import requests

response = requests.options('http://google.com/')
print(response.headers['Allow'])
```

`>> GET, HEAD`

Comment: While this would generally work for most sites, it seems like for some this wouldn't, I tried it with http://neopets.com and it doesn't seem like the response header contains an Allow attribute